# как сделать 2 канала в Notification?

Tags: java, android

Есть задача сделать 2 канала в Notification....
оба должны включаться как startForeground и выключаться stopForeground, но работать должны 2 двух разных Notification(по id)..... и как то надо их выключать видимость, но при этом что бы они все так же работали... но у меня вовсе ничего не получается....

```
я делаю так:
    startForeground(notificationId, updateNotification());


    private Notification updateNotification()  {
        PendingIntent action = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel1 = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_1_ID, "Channel 1", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel1.setDescription("This is channel 1");
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel1);

            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID);
        }
        else
        {
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        }

        return builder.setContentIntent(action)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.service11))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.service22))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                //.setContentIntent(action)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();
    }
```

меняю во втором все данные в CHANNEL_1_ID и все ровно появляется все в одном Notification

Comment: Может у вас `notificationId` всегда одинаковый?

Comment: не я разделил их! private int notificationId = 101, notificationId1 = 202;

Comment: ничего уж не понимаю

Comment: А как и где вы меняете CHANNEL_1_ID? Очень смущает то, что вы говорите, что меняете, но в самом вопросе у вас захардкоженные константы.

Comment: глобально объявил     public static final  String CHANNEL_1_ID = "channel1";
    public static final  String CHANNEL_2_ID = "channel2";

Comment: У вас в коде ещё виден хардкод для `"Channel 1"` и `"This is channel 1"`. Не факт, что это как-то влияет, но попробуйте это тоже менять, если не меняете.

Comment: тоже меняю это! безрезультатно

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что у вас при разных ID уведомления и канала уведомления друг-друга перезатирают? Если да, то это предельно странно. Или они не перезатирают, но при этом имеют один и тот же канал? Может у вас в девайсе проблема? Пробовали на других запускать?

Comment: да все так! пробывал на 3ех разных телефонах! одно и тоже

Comment: Что именно "так"? Перезатираются уведомления или не меняется канал?

Comment: одно другим перезатирается

Comment: Крайне странно. Выведите в логи (или посмотрите в дебаге) какой именно у вас ID для уведомления реально используется. Такое должно происходить только при одинаковых ID, насколько я знаю.

Answer (score 0):

```
PendingIntent action = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
Если система видит, что создаваемый с таким флагом PendingIntent похож на существующий, то она отменит (удалит) существующий.

замените его на 0

```
PendingIntent action = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class), 0);
```